# How do I increase the clickable area of a point in Highcharts so that whenever the point is 'active' a click can be recorded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

Slightly convoluted question, I apologise, but let me explain further.

With a line chart in Highcharts.js, moving your mouse into the area of the point hovers over the point and loads the tooltip. I have some click event operations working fine, but I would like to modify them so that you can 'click' the points when the mouse is not actually over them but simply within range to hover over the point.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: This might be slightly messy and not the best way of doing it, but could you put the handle into a div which is slightly larger? And then use the new div as the handle.

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve. One thing, can be capute chart's click and check the distance to the nearest point - it would be helpful if you set up a live example on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

From highcharts website

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/events-click/

```
chart: {
    events: {
        click: function (event) {
            var label = this.renderer.label(
                    'x: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(event.xAxis[0].value, 2) + ', y: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(event.yAxis[0].value, 2),
                    event.xAxis[0].axis.toPixels(event.xAxis[0].value),
                    event.yAxis[0].axis.toPixels(event.yAxis[0].value)
                )
                    .attr({
                        fill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
                        padding: 10,
                        r: 5,
                        zIndex: 8
                    })
                    .css({
                        color: '#FFFFFF'
                    })
                    .add();

            setTimeout(function () {
                label.fadeOut();
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't quite what I asked but thank you for taking the time to respond

Comment: I must have misunderstood you, do you want to capture the click within a radius of a point?